# Operating Systems . What is difference between sleep and suspend?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, process, operating-system

I can't figure out the difference between the two states of the thread. Please explain this difference.

Comment: Tannenbaum? That still a thing? :) I think the difference is not that big, they will not be actively scheduled by the OS for a while. The suspended thread can be waiting for io (or a condition variable) and will be woken up by the os based on a condition.  A sleeping thread will be (automatically) woken up after a certain amount of time. (Probably not a formally correct answer, but more my working model)

Comment: @PepijnKramer If Tannenbaum is outdated, what book or article can you recommend me to study the basics of operating systems?

Comment: No I think it probably is still valid today because it describes concepts at a fundamental level, I was just (pleasantly) surprised you know it. I used the first edition back in college (about 30 years ago now).

Comment: I always thought it was the most popular book about operating systems

Comment: It certainly has been around, so probably yes :)

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly a matter of jargon. Sleep implies that the thread is suspended for a specific period of time and will be re-scheduled after that time has gone past.

Suspend simply means it's not being run by the OS because it's been blocked (e.g. waiting for I/O) or it's asked to be suspended (e.g. it wants to sleep).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bazza, it's a choice made by whoever defines the API of the OS or the library that provides `sleep` and `suspend` calls.

In most of the APIs that I have encountered, `sleep` is something that a thread can only do to itself, and `suspend`, which is paired with `resume`, is something that only makes sense to do to another thread.

`Sleep` may be used in production code to provide time delays, or in the heart of a real-time-ish scheduling algorithm. `Suspend` and `resume`, on the other hand usually are documented as "dangerous" calls that should not be used in production code, but which are made available for diagnostic purposes.

---

The use of either of those words is independent of the word "blocked," which usually just means that there is some reason—any reason—why some thread should not be allowed to run.